# The problem in GetMapping ("blog / $ {id}") does not work

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc

Я начал изучать springboot mvс, и у меня возникла такая проблема. Я пытаюсь отобразить одну статью через ее идентификатор, и все будет правильно, но когда я нажимаю на ссылку блог / {id}. Косая черта между блогом и id и страница не загружается. Однако, если вы вставите косую черту между ними вручную, страница загрузится.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Это часть кода моего контроллера blogController, этот метод отвечает за выделение статьи отдельно через идентификатор и отображение ее в отдельном представлении blog-details.html. Это изображение проблемы. [image: the link when i click to the button which have ti direct blog/${id}] между blog и $ {id} нет символа "/", и это не работает. P.S Я использовал систему управления базами данных mongoDb Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Переведите ваш вопрос на русский язык

Comment: На скриншоте у тебя код контроллера и он верный. Опять же ручной ввод адреса работает. У тебя на странице ссылка генерируется неправильно. В видимой части ставится `/`, а в самом `href` - не ставится. Например, `<a href="localhost:8000/blog$id">localhost:8000/blog/$id</a>` - здесь видимый текст правильный, но сама ссылка - нет.